# 2 Way Sync Excel 2013 Spreadsheet and Sharepoint 2013 List

Tags: excel, list, sharepoint, synchronization, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to do a 2-way sync with an excel spreadsheet and a list on my sharepoint 2013 online public site. Research has told me that the best approach, without using 3rd party solutions, would be to use Access 2013, and to first sync the excel spreadsheet to the access database (I've done this). Next would be to sync the Access database with a sharepoint list. When I try to do this, it publishes the table as a list, but if any changes are made to the excel spreadsheet, it's not updated on the sharepoint list. Is there a specific way this needs to be done? I wasn't able to find any good documentation on this, especially for 2013 versions.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Were you able achieve this?

Comment: No, if I remember correctly I ended up throwing the whole idea away and imported the Excel data to a MySQL database and rewrote the SharePoint site as a webapp in PHP. I can't believe this was only ~5 years ago, feels so much longer. Good luck!